# Styles in Excel using Open XML

Tags: c#, openxml

I am quite new to C# & got stuck with a problem.

I am trying to add some style to the Excel using OpenXML, though it is not drawing borders, the fills (foreground & background colors) and alignment to the cells. I tried many times with different ways, though I am not able to do so.
The following code is not generating any error. Compiling successfully, however not giving the expected output.

Following is the actual output:

[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Qq8.jpg)

Following is the expected output:

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9zQB.jpg)

The requirement is that only the top row to have this specific style, how can I achieve it?

**Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.**

Code snippet:

```
private void ExportDataSet()

{

WorkbookStylesPart wbsp = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();

wbsp.Stylesheet = CreateStylesheet();

wbsp.Stylesheet.Save();

}   


private static DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Stylesheet CreateStylesheet()
{
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Stylesheet stylesheet1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Stylesheet();

#region Font
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fonts fonts = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fonts() { Count = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)2U};

// FontID = 0 (The Default Font)
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Font font0 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Font();
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.FontSize fontSize0 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.FontSize() { Val = 11D };
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Color color0 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Color() { Theme = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)1U };
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.FontName fontName0 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.FontName() { Val = "Calibri" };

font0.Append(fontSize0);
font0.Append(color0);
font0.Append(fontName0);

// FontID = 1
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Font font1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Font();
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.FontSize fontSize1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.FontSize() { Val = 12D };
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.FontName fontName1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.FontName() { Val = "Calibri" };
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Color color1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Color() { Rgb = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.HexBinaryValue("5B9BD5") };
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Bold bold1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Bold() { Val = true };

// Foreground & Background not working
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.ForegroundColor foregroundColor1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.ForegroundColor() { Rgb = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.HexBinaryValue("FF00FF00") };
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BackgroundColor backgroundColor1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BackgroundColor() { Rgb = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.HexBinaryValue("FF00FF00") };


font1.Append(fontSize1);
font1.Append(fontName1);
font1.Append(color1);
font1.Append(bold1);
font1.Append(foregroundColor1);
font1.Append(backgroundColor1);

fonts.Append(font1);

int fontIndex = fonts.Count() - 1;
#endregion

#region CellBorders
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Borders borders = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Borders() { Count = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)2U };

// Border ID = 0 (The Default Border)
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Border border0 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Border();

DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.LeftBorder leftBorder0 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.LeftBorder();
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.RightBorder rightBorder0 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.RightBorder();
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.TopBorder topBorder0 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.TopBorder();
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BottomBorder bottomBorder0 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BottomBorder();

border0.Append(leftBorder0);
border0.Append(rightBorder0);
border0.Append(topBorder0);
border0.Append(bottomBorder0);

// Border ID = 1
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Border border1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Border();

DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.LeftBorder leftBorder = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.LeftBorder() { Style = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BorderStyleValues.Thick };
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.RightBorder rightBorder = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.RightBorder() { Style = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BorderStyleValues.Thick };
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.TopBorder topBorder = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.TopBorder() { Style = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BorderStyleValues.Thick };
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BottomBorder bottomBorder = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BottomBorder() { Style = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BorderStyleValues.Thick };

border1.Append(leftBorder);
border1.Append(rightBorder);
border1.Append(topBorder);
border1.Append(bottomBorder);

borders.Append(border1);

int borderIndex = borders.Count() - 1;
#endregion

#region Fill
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fills fills = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fills() { Count = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)3U };

// Fill ID = 0 (The Default Fill)
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fill fill0 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fill();
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PatternFill patternFill0 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PatternFill() { PatternType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PatternValues.None };     // required, reserved by Excel
fill0.Append(patternFill0);

// Fill ID = 1 (The default fill of Gray)
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fill fill1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fill();
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PatternFill patternFill1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PatternFill() { PatternType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PatternValues.Gray125 };  // required, reserved by Excel
fill1.Append(patternFill1);

// Fill ID = 2
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fill fill2 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fill();
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PatternFill patternFill2 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PatternFill() { PatternType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PatternValues.Solid };    // customized Pattern value
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.ForegroundColor foregroundColorFill2 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.ForegroundColor() { Rgb = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.HexBinaryValue("FF00FF00") };
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BackgroundColor backgroundColorFill2 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BackgroundColor() { Rgb = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.HexBinaryValue("5B9BD500") };

patternFill2.Append(foregroundColorFill2);
patternFill2.Append(backgroundColorFill2);
fill2.Append(patternFill2);

fills.Append(fill2);

int fillIndex = fills.Count() - 1;
#endregion

#region Alignment
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Alignment alignment = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Alignment()
{
    Horizontal = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left,
    Vertical = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.VerticalAlignmentValues.Center
};
#endregion

#region Cell Style Formats & Cell Formats
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellFormats cellFormats0 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellFormats() { Count = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)1U };

// Cell Format ID = 0 (The Default Cell Format)
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellFormat cellFormat0 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellFormat()
{
    NumberFormatId = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)0U,
    FontId = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)0U,
    FillId = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)0U,
    BorderId = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)0U,
    FormatId = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)0U
};

cellFormats0.Append(cellFormat0);

// Cell Format ID = 1
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellFormat cellFormat1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellFormat()
{
    NumberFormatId = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)1U,
    FontId = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)1U,
    FillId = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)2U,
    BorderId = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)1U,
    FormatId = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)1U,
    ApplyBorder = true,
    ApplyFont = true,
    ApplyFill = true,
};
cellFormats0.Append(cellFormat1);

DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellStyles cellStyles = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellStyles() { Count = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)1U };
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellStyle cellStyle = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellStyle()
{
    Name = "Normal",
    FormatId = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)0U,
    BuiltinId = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)1U
};

cellStyles.Append(cellStyle);
#endregion

#region Stylesheet
stylesheet1.Append(fonts);
stylesheet1.Append(fills);
stylesheet1.Append(borders);
stylesheet1.Append(cellFormats0);
stylesheet1.Append(cellStyles);
#endregion

return stylesheet1;
}
```

Comment: My standard comment:  Download the "OpenXML Productivity Tool" from the Microsoft site.  This will let you "reflect" over the code that would be needed to create a Spreadsheet/WordDoc/etc that you create in an office app.  So, you can create a document (in Excel or Word...), open it up in the tool, and see the code needed to get things working.  Even better, you can create an XLSX file, save it, make a single change, and save that with a different name.  Then you can open the tool and "diff" the 2 files to see what the differences are in the code/structure.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks, I tried using 'OpenXML Productivity Tool' too, however it was not of a much help.
I debug & found the issue. It has been resolved.
The issue with above code is that the default Font, Fill, Border etc are not appended, which was causing the problem.
I am still not able to get how to restrict this style to only the 1st or top row.